# Why do I have to add + i + into the second WebElement in Selenium Java loop?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium Java I often write For Loop's, why do I have to add `+ i +` into the second WebElement, Please see the attached example

```
for (int i = 1; i <= secondaryLinks.size(); i++){
    WebElement links = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".FeatureHighlight .el:nth-of-type("+ i +") a"));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's an index - it finds the *nth* element that matches the selector.

Comment: It would help if the question was not in the title.

Comment: very confusing title

Comment: One of the people complaining about the question being in the title is more than capable of fixing it.  How constructive of them.

Comment: @Archer if they don't comment/complain then the OP won't know it's a poorly worded question. IMO, the OP should be responsible for wording their own question... but that's just me.

Comment: @JeffC We earn edit privileges by being active and answering questions.  Editing a question to make it clearer is not a mutually exclusive act, and can be accompanied with an explanation, as per the "Edit Summary" box.

Comment: It was my first Question on here. I don't see the issue. I asked for help on the issue, not about how to articulate this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for loops with indexing. You can approach it by using `findElements()` and iterating over elements having `el` class inside elements having `FeatureHighlight` class (`.FeatureHighlight .el` CSS selector). For every element found, find the inner link by tag name.

Sample implementation:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".FeatureHighlight .el"));
for (WebElement element: elements) {   
    WebElement link = element.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Alecxe, The for each loop above is great for  just finding one Element, but I need to find multiple elements, e.g. header. paragraph text so on. So the for each wouldn't work. My biggest Query is why do I need + i + in the css selector.

Comment: @Littlen I am still not sure why the for each would not work, you can use the `element` WebElement to find inner elements like header, paragraph etc. Could you post the HTML code of the page and your desired result?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but my question has now been answered.

Comment: Due to the sensitivity of my client I can't share HTML. 
` for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h5"));
            element.isDisplayed();

            WebElement elementTwo = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" p"));
               

            WebElement elementThree = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" a"));
               
            }
          
        }`